# ¿Cómo podría configurar el zoom de Firefox para todas las páginas web?

Tags: firefox, configuración, zoom

¿Hay alguna manera de establecer el valor del zoom (por ejemplo al 80%) para que al iniciar Firefox o abrir una nueva pestaña. El zoom predeterminado sea 80%?

Answer (score 1):

**Sin extensión:**

1- Pones esto en el la barra de navegación (y accedes):`about:config`

2- Aceptas los riesgos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
3- Buscas: `browser.zoom.siteSpecific`

4- Le das doble click para ponerlo en False (tiene que estar en false)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora respetara el zoom que pongas, es decir, si pones zoom 80% todas las páginas lo tendrán (aunque cierres y abras el navegador) *no afecta a los iconos, etc...

**Con extensión:**

https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/zoom-page/

Answer (score 0):

## Sin addons

1. Escribir en la barra de dirección `about:config`
2. Aceptar los riesgos
3. Buscar la propiedad `layout.css.devPixelsPerPx`
4. Setearla en `0.8` (80%)

**Nota:** Esto también cambiará el tamaño de los íconos y pestañas.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió... voy a averiguar si se puede modificar solamente el zoom dejando la interfaz como está y lo aporto acá mismo. Gracias nuevamente